# Getting Full Name from Facebook from a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello so I am just starting out with the Facebook iOS SDK and I can sign in to Facebook easy but I am having problems figuring out how to get the users full name and displaying it in a UILabel.  Also I am doing this from a UIViewController and so far everything I have seen on the internet has taken place in the app delegate, however, I don't want it to be done from the delegate, it just is not the right place to do this i want it in a UIViewController so when a button is pressed you can sign in to Facebook.  The Facebook SDK just seems complicated right now as its my first time using it.

EDIT:
okay heres some of my code.
This is in the view controller:

```
-(void)createfbInstance {

Facebook* fb = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FB_APP_ID andDelegate:self];
self.facebook = fb;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_about_me", nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
} 
}
```

So I just set it up like the Facebook tutorial
Then I try to send a request with graph path:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

FBAppDelegate* appDelegate = (FBAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"name" andDelegate:self];
}
```

Then try and receive the request:

```
 - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

 }
```

Sorry I got frustrated and deleted the code out of that method.
and then in the delegate I have the Facebook property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook* Facebook;
```

There is other code in the file but this seemed like the most important code.

Comment: is the first method you posted (`createfbInstance`) in the app delegate? You said in your edit it's in the view controller, if that's true put that method in the delegate and make sure it gets called.  Same thing with `fbDidLogin`, which is a delegate method for `FBSessionDelegate` then remove the last two lines of `fbDidLogin` and put it in your view controller somewhere.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this before.  Try this: `[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];` instead of `requestWithGraphPath:@"name"`  The graph path is the API method that you will call, the list can be found at http://graph.facebook.com

Comment: I think you just fixed my problem! I put the delegate methods in the app delegate and did what you said last and now the methods are called and FBRequest successfully loads a result! The only problem I am having is requesting "me" from the graph path returns my entire profile information (of course) and I need the users name, I'm sure I can figure this out if I search around. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you request "me" you get the currently logged in user's name.  If you are talking about getting a friend's name then it's `/me/friends` or if you know the user whose name you want you can do `{theirID}`

Comment: This is what I tried it worked great:    if ([request.url isEqual:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"]) {
        self.loginName = [((NSDictionary*)result) objectForKey:@"name"];

Comment: Great!  Glad to see you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

In whatever class you need to access the Facebook API from you need to include the following files (in the header file):

```
#import "FBConnect.h"
#import "YOUR_APP_DELEGATE.h"
```

and also make your class implement the `FBRequestDelegate` Delegate.

Then in order to use it you simply do the following:

```
    YOURAPPDELEGATE *appDelegate = (YOURAPPDELEGATE*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

With that you can now access the Facebook property you have in your delegate allowing you to access the API.

Now you need to add the method `- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result` in your view controller so you can receive the response.

So now you can call

```
        [appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"APICALLHERE" andDelegate:self];
```

and you will now receive the response in the `request:didLoad:` method which you can then do whatever you want with.

Comment: This dod not work for me.  I do not think the method - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result is being called

Comment: Is the property in your delegate called facebook?  (is there `Facebook *facebook` and `@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook` in its header). I know that my code works, not only is it mentioned in the iOS tutorial in the facebook developer site, but I'm also currently using it in an app I'm working on

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I have in the header. The app does switch to safari to sign in but I can't get the users name

Comment: Yeah I will have to wait till tomorrow.